# Bootstrap navbar gets stuck

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a responsive site. On mobile, when  clicking inside a textbox, the keyboard comes up and pushes the screen up, hiding the navbar. If you click a button while the keyboard is still up, the keyboard disappears but the navbar gets stuck halfway up the page (I'm guessing where it was on page beforehand). I've attached some pictures. I'm using default bootstrap code with just color changes via css (no positioning or anything, just changing the colors). I've attached 3 images, normal, textbox open, and after clicking a button while textbox was open. Anyone have any ideas why or how to fix it?

Here's the html for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top padding-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container padding-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html" id="logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #79a137;
    border-color: #79a137;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #79a137;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #79a137;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #79a137;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #79a137;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #000000;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #79a137;
    }
}
```

[image: Normal]
[image: Text Box Open]
[image: Error]

Comment: we can't debug with pictures, please provide some code and it would be helpul to include a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example of the reproducible problem and viewport widths.

Comment: You must have taken efforts to fiddle your code instead image trivia!

Comment: Attached html and css snippets